# BaggingClassifier give the same result in different executions

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I am testing a simple model (knn) and trying to compare results with an Ensamble.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
data = load_iris()
y = data.target
X = data.data
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
bagging = BaggingClassifier(knn, max_samples=0.5, max_features=0.5)

print "KNN Score:\t", cross_val_score(knn, X, y, cv=5, n_jobs=-1).mean()
print "Bagging Score:\t", cross_val_score(bagging, X, y, cv=5, n_jobs=-1).mean()
```

But everytime I run it the code I get the same error estimation... Should not be different every time?

Comment: Without the data its hard to say.

Comment: I have added some data as example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two scores that are calculated in your code. The first one,

```
print "KNN Score:\t", cross_val_score(knn, X, y, cv=5, n_jobs=-1).mean()
```

will always return the same value. The reason is that there is nothing random in this process. The data is exactly the same, and the devision into 5 folds is exactly the same (as indicated [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold), the data is split into 5 consecutive folds).

However, when calculating the following score:

```
print "Bagging Score:\t", cross_val_score(bagging, X, y, cv=5, n_jobs=-1).mean()
```

there is a randomness in the process. For example, since `max_samples=0.5`, you draw at random half of the samples to train each base estimator. Hence each time you run the code you may get a different result.

Comment: Yes... but the problem is that I don´t get different results... in this lineprint "Bagging Score:\t", cross_val_score(bagging, X, y, cv=5, n_jobs=-1).mean()

Comment: This is quite strange... Maybe somewhere in your system the random seed is fixed? Try to do the following: add the parameter random_state to the BaggingClassifier. i.e., run your code with bagging = BaggingClassifier(knn, max_samples=0.5, max_features=0.5,random_state=2). Then run the code but switch the random state. For example, run the code with bagging = BaggingClassifier(knn, max_samples=0.5, max_features=0.5,random_state=1). Do you still get the same result?

Comment: I think you are right. I have tried the same code in a different computer (with Windows) and I see different results... Besides, I had tried before setting different seeds in `random_state` parameter and it threw different results. Thanks for the response...